# How do I make my app loading faster and validate Facebook access token in background process

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using [**Facebook PHP SDK**](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) to make API calls for my app. Each new user use my app, script will save/update everything to database like `username`, `sex`, `avatar`, etc..

```
if ($user) {
    try {
        $me                 = $facebook->api('/me');
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $me['id'];
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
        unset($_SESSION['userid']);
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

After user logged to my app, script will used only `$_SESSION['userid']` to retrieve user information and every pages on my app running smooth and faster. The problem here user still can use the app if already logout from Facebook.

If I call the `facebook.php` file on every page and sure will be slow to load.

Question :

How do I use the Facebook PHP SDK properly? If current `$_SESSION['userid']` same with Facebook access token (current logged id) don't call the `facebook.php` file.

Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the facebook.php file once you have a valid access token. All you do is send an HTTP GET to `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={token}` and process the JSON response.